# Avoid manual creation of lambda to wrap the call to new[]: to be used as a generator function in std::generate

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, new-operator, stl-algorithm

### Short Version

Currently, I manually create a lambda function for the `new []`, as follows:

```
[](){ return new double[3]; }
```

This lambda is later used as a generator function in the call to [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](){ return new double[3]; });
```

Can I avoid the creation of this lambda and use some more standard functionality/syntax sugar/alternatives? C++17 is preferred; however, if C++20 (or some proposal) offers something better, I am very interested as well.

The long version provides some background, and an existing solution for a similar situation, when [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is used to deallocate the memory.

---

### Long Version with Background

#### Need

1. Create `std::vector` that stores `double*` pointers, which point to 1-D arrays of fixed size.
2. Pass this structure to the library function that will fill it with data.
3. Use the filled data.
4. Clear the allocated memory.

#### Conditions

- Due to (2), I do not have control over the type of argument for the library function; thus, I am limited to using `std::vector<double*>` no matter how other containers might be better suited.
- Want clean, minimalistic, and efficient code
- In particular, I started from simple plain `for`-loops and decided to go for [STL `<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

#### Initial code

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // (1)
    size_t numElems = 10;
    std::vector<double*> vec(numElems);
    for (size_t i=0; i<numElems; i++)
    {
        vec[i] = new double[3];
    }

    // (2)-(3) SOME ACTIVITY with vec

    // (4)
    for (size_t i=0; i<numElems; i++)
    {
        delete [] vec[i];
    }
}
```

where, for simplicity, I hardcoded the `numElems` in the vector `vec`, and used hardcoded size of the `double*` array to be `3`. The passing to external function and activity in (2)–(3) are skipped. This code works.

#### New code

I tried the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    // (1)
    size_t numElems = 10;
    std::vector<double*> vec(numElems);
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](){ return new double[3]; });

    // (2)-(3) SOME ACTIVITY with vec

    // (4)
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::default_delete<double[]>());
}
```

which also works fine.

#### Question

In the revised version, the deletion is performed via [`std::default_delete<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) applied via [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) that conveniently provides "a function representation" of the language keyword `delete []` (a bit sloppy wording).

Is there a similar way "to represent" `new []`? Or am I stuck creating the lambda manually to be used as a generator function argument for [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)?

Comment: Even though your library wants raw pointers, I'd go out of my way to avoid using `new` and `delete` manually. You can create a vector of vectors, then a vector of pointers pointing to them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `numElems` is quite large, and I have at least 3 of them to deal with in each thread; thus, an overhead of at least `10*numElems*sizeof(ptr*)*numThreads`. For some typical scenario, this will result in the minimum overhead of `3*1E+6*8*48 = 1 GB`, which is significant. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Does the library need exactly `std::vector<double*>`? Or do you just pass a `double**`?

Comment: @KamilCuk `std::vector<double*>` is the only availbale interface.

Comment: @AntonMenshov If you need to reduce overhead, allocate the memory in a single block (owned by a single `unique_ptr`), then create a vector of pointers to it (like one of the answers suggests). Then there will be even less overhead than in your current approach (because the heap has to have some overhead per block).

Comment: Currently, if anything in your code throws (including `new`), you leak memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct default_new {
    typename std::decay<T>::type operator() (){ return new T; }
};

int main() {
    size_t numElems = 10;
    std::vector<double*> vec(numElems);
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), default_new<double[3]>());

    // (2)-(3) SOME ACTIVITY with vec

    // (4)
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::default_delete<double[]>());
}
```

works. I do not know if such is provided from standard library, I believe not.

Comment: quite neat! I did not think of doing a template with `std::decay`. This will help to some extent since I need those not only for `std::vector<double*>`, but for other types and other sizes.

Answer (score 3):

A single heap allocation costs a few pointers worth per element in memory overhead. So if you're dealing with an enormous vector of pointers, it might save memory to have a single allocation, and a vector as a view:

```cpp
struct vector3 {
    vector3(size_t numElements) 
        // use new[] over std::make_unique to avoid value initialization,
        // since it's assumed the library function will initialize the data
        : storage(new std::array<double, 3>[numElements]) {
        view.reserve(numElements);
        std::transform(
            storage.get(), 
            storage.get() + numElements, 
            std::back_inserter(view),
            [](auto& a) { return a.data(); }); // no good substitute for lambda here
    }
    std::unique_ptr<std::array<double, 3>[]> storage;
    std::vector<double*> view;
};
```

usage:

```cpp
vector3 myVector(10);
library_function(myVector.view);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6x4PEs

EDIT: moved into class to guarantee lifetimes per Swift - Friday Pie's suggestion.

Comment: Just have to be sure that life of storage isn't shorter than one of vector ,composing them would be nice

Comment: Good point @SwiftFridayPie, moved them into a class to enforce order. Thanks!

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::array<double, 3>>` must be `std::unique_ptr<std::array<double, 3>[]>`. Also I suggest using `make_unique` instead of a naked `new`.